# AutoHotkey: How to fix "this line does not contain a recognized action" when trying to send an sql-statement?

Tags: sql, autohotkey

I'm currently trying to write an Autohotkey command, which pastes a SQL code, but i only get this message:

> Error at line 3.  Line Text: Create table #tmp (
>   Error: This line does not contain a recognized action.
>   The script was not reloaded; the old Version will remain in effect.

there are also some variations of this message.

I already tried to use SendRaw or SendInput. Even the escape character ´ does not work. Putting it in quotation marks neither. I do not have any clues anymore.

```
:*:sql::
(
--drop table #tmp 
Create table #tmp (
    Refnr int identity (1,1) not null, 
    row1 varchar(8000) null, 
    number int null 
    )
insert into #tmp (row1, number)
select top 20 row1, count(*) from tableA 
group by row1 
order by 2 desc
select * from #tmp order by 3 desc
)
```

well, i expected it to send the SQL-Statement, but I'm just getting errors like the one above. Sometimes it refers to the line "Create Table #tmp(", sometimes to "insert into #tmp (row1, number)". And I don't know what to do. 
Does anyone has a clue and  can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mind your closing brackets/parentheses. You can use the back-tick <kbd>`</kbd> character to escape characters inside your text.

For example:

```
:*:sql::
(
--drop table #tmp 
Create table #tmp (
    Refnr int identity (1,1) not null, 
    row1 varchar(8000) null, 
    number int null 
    `)
insert into #tmp (row1, number)
select top 20 row1, count(*) from tableA 
group by row1 
order by 2 desc
select * from #tmp order by 3 desc
)
```